# how to create an msi file from outlook addin 2007?

Tags: outlook, windows-installer, add-in

I have created an Outlook Addon that generates a popup new mail alert and would now like to  generate an msi file for setting it up in other computers.
How can I do it?

Comment: This is not a straightforward task but fortunately, you can find a walkthrough and sample code on MSDN: - [**Deploying a VSTO 3.0 solution for the Office 2007 using Windows Installers**](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VSTO3MSI/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=729) 1. [**Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer (Part 1 of 2)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx) 2. [**Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Wind

Comment: FWIW there are several VSTO blog articles on my website. Also, if you want to use free InstallShield Limited Edition I could give you a template project that takes care of 95% of the details for you. It gives me a nice head start when a customer wants an Office AddIn installer.

Comment: I'd like that. the MSDN code didn't work for me.

Comment: I just not saw this.  Do you still need it?